# evaluating variable int/string

Tags: java, string

```
 int x = 20;


 double d = 3.1416;


 String s ="H";
```

those are my variables and I have to give the type the next lines evaluate to.

```
d/x + "";
```

is evaluating to  double variable type (0.15708), is that correct?

Comment: @Monica Pertrusio, my best advice is for you to test these kinds of things for yourself - it will spare you a lot of time... E.g: print out the value of `double = d/x;` and see what happens.

Comment: so then it must be a string right?

Comment: @Centril I tried but it didn't work, I'll try again tho thanks

Comment: @MonicaPertrusio You have to accept an answer

Answer (score 0):

You'd be right if we didn't have that pesky `""` at the end!

Add `""` to the end of something like this makes it into a `String`. It can actually be a handy shortcut - instead of having to use something like `String.valueOf()`, you could just do `4/2 + ""`, which makes it into a string.

To reiterate,

`d/x` would be a `double`, since you are adding a floating point.

But a `double + "" = String`.

I hope that helps. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong.
`d/x + "";` is a `String`. 
This happens because when you are using the `+` operator, if any of the 2 sides is a `String`, then string concatenation happens and of course the result is a `String`.

By the way you can check that indeed it is a `String` by using the `getClass()` method. Note that if you remove the `""` and use the `getClass()` you will get an error. This happens because `d/x` is a `double`, i.e a primitive type, so it can't use the method `getClass()`.
 **In your example:**
`System.out.println((d/x + "").getClass());` will return `java.lang.String`